# Automatically insert thousands of review blocks into pages of a wordpress site

Tags: html, css, wordpress, elementor, review

i try to ask for help here. I have a wordpress site where I use Elementor for pages.

Assuming to create an area of ​​the site where there are reviews divided into pages with menus for navigating them.

The problem is that there are thousands of reviews, how can I avoid having to enter them one by one? is there an automatic system that inserts them all into pages and also allows me to add them in the future?

And if it exists, is it possible to give it the style I want?

I've already done a similar thing by creating individual pages and inserting them the way I want. But when the reviews start to grow it becomes difficult and you have to create even hundreds of pages.

I have the reviews in a csv with columns "review" and "name".

Thanks!

Comment: Create custom post type reviews and the fields you need. There are many examples here and on google how to do it. About the import  I would recommend to use any of the popular plugins for importing like WP ALL IMPORT. Again use google an you will find many plugins for import.

Comment: @MartinMirchev Would you be so kind to explain better what you mean or link something about it? I'm having trouble translating what you said into my language and I don't understand. I'm talking about this "Create custom post type reviews and the fields you need"

Comment: How to create custom post type - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48711935/how-to-create-a-new-custom-post-types-in-wordpress. More info here - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/ . How to create fields - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/. Or using plugin such as Metabox or ACF. Like i said use google and you will find many tutorials and documentation also videos.